# Cardinality of the family of factorials of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Fix a nonempty subset $X$ of $\mathbb N$. A number $a\in X$ will be called irreducible if it is not a product of smaller elements of $X$. We call $X$ factorial if any number in $X$ has a unique factorization into irreducibles (up to the order of factors).

> Prove that the family of all factorial sets has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

- Of course it has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, because the family of all subsets of $\mathbb N$ has that cardinality.

But I don't know how to get that it is exactly of that size. I thought about assuming it has power $\aleph_0$, and somehow using Cantor's diagonal argument, but this would not be enough without assuming extra assumptions (the continuum hypothesis).

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It matters where you close that unmatched parenthesis! Are you asking us to assume CH in any case? If not, then the family of subsets of $\Bbb N$ does not necessarily have cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: The set of primes $P$ has the same cardinality as the set $N$. Any subset of $P$ is factorial. That part of the collection of all factorial sets already has the same cardinality as the set of all subsets of $N$.

Comment: How do you define $\aleph_1$ and how do you define "continuum"?

Comment: I edited the question to remove the erroneous terminology. My advice is to not use symbols if you do not understand what they mean. It makes the question unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Aleph one is the smallest cardinal number greater than aleph one.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo what do You mean?

Comment: Why do you think that the set has cardinality $\aleph_1$, rather than continuum?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I was wrong. Sorry. Continuum is the right word here.

Comment: Okay, good that we cleared that up. (There are many people who make this mistake, and many of them are not even aware that it's a mistake. This is why I insisted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that every set of prime numbers is a factorial. Simply because every prime number is irreducible.

Now ask yourself, how many prime numbers are there? The answer, of course, is $\aleph_0$. Now ask yourself, how many *sets* of prime numbers are there?